# How to fetch products related to every product within an array?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce2

I’ve got products which are related to various products of another type (product.accessories).

Now I’m trying to fetch all products related to *every* single product within a given array.

My first attempt was to prepend an array item *'and'* in order to tell *relatedTo* to match all products:

```
{# simplified code #}
{% set accessories = craft.products().type('accessory') %}
{% set accessories = ['and'] | merge(accessories) %}
{% set products = craft.products().relatedTo(accessories) | all %}
```

Which leads to an error: *'array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, object given'*.

I know I could use the object syntax, but this would require an additional traversal in the first place:

```
{# simplified code #}
{% set accessories = craft.products().type('accessory') %}
{% set constraint = ['and'] %}
{% for accessory in accessories %}
    {% set constraint = constraint | merge([{element: accessory}]) %}
{% endfor %}
{% set products = craft.products().relatedTo(constraint) | all %}
```

Is there a way to mach all products without the need of an additional loop?